# PHP: Posting JSON without cURL

Tags: php, json

```
$msg = ['text' => 'foo'];
$data_string = json_encode($msg);
```

I need to POST a JSON-Object to an external Server via PHP.
The problem is, that I can not install cURL or anything else on the server as it's not hosted by me.
Is there a possible solution with PHP or do I have to use something else, like jQuery?

Comment: Have you checked that cURL isn't already installed? It's standard at most hosting providers. Guzzle might be an option, I suppose. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: have you checked stream-context-create , fopen , etc ?

Comment: 1. yes, cURL isn't installed, as I get an error while trying to initialize it
@Leonid Vinikov I just did and guess what, my provider blocked file_get_contents, so now I don't think there is any possibility for my server to POST anywhere...but thanks